# OpenCV detectMultiScale: How to find largest object using ios

Tags: ios, opencv

I am using `OpenCV` in IOS(iPhone). I am using `detectMultiScale` to detect faces. Currently, it detects multiple objects. I would like it to detect the largest object only. When I use `detectMultiScale(Image, faces, 1.1, 3, CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT)` it has no effect. How do I go about it? Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the OpenCV source, you can see that `CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT` has no effect. Look at the `flags` parameter at [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale), it says '*It is not used for a new cascade.*'. What you need to do is iterate through the faces and get the biggest one by looking their widths and heights.

Code is something like following:

```
detectMultiScale(Image, faces, 1.1, 3);
cv::Rect biggestRect(0,0,0,0);
for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
{
   cv::Rect rect = faces[i];
   if(rect.width > biggestRect.width)
   {
      biggestRect = rect;
   }
}

cv::Mat biggestFace = Image(biggestRect);
```